# Keyboard layout configuration in MAC OSX is being very buggy

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-layout

I'm using an apple keyboard (not sure which country it's supposed to be, but the `/~ key is next to the shift key). I'm experiencing a number of problems, which I think are related

- Pressing the `/~ key outputs the ± character
- If I switch the keyboard layout to a correct one (eg Canadian English) and open keyboard viewer the correct layout is displayed until I press any key, then the layout shown on the screen changes to a different (US English I think, although the heading at the top of the on screen keyboard still says "Canadian English"
- Each time I open the keyboard viewer it gets bigger

Has anyone else ever come across similar behaviour?

Comment: It's the International English layout. `~ next to left shift, §± below escape, otherwise like US English (with the exception of return key and \| placement).

Comment: Does this behavior occur on all user accounts on your system? Create a new account and test it.

Comment: @Daniel Beck - the bugs still happen when I choose US - International (English International isn't an option) - it keeps switching the layout to an incorrect one as soon as I press any key. And I don't have the privileges to create another account. I'll ask our IT support to help